# Autoplay clappr player inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click, autoplay

I'm building an html file for personal use that's supposed to show me a few websites, one of them being this Clappr player.

Since this is going to be used in a Chromium kiosk mode, I need it to autoplay.

I don't own the page with the link provided above.

So far I've tried to simulate a click event using javascript, but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my shortened html file. Any suggestions on how I could get this player to start autoplaying?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#webcam {
        border: none;
    }
</style>  
</head>

<body>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <iframe id="webcam" src="https://player.livespotting.tv/jwp-weather.html?alias=PS_98e04&amp;station=38" scrolling="no" width="512" height="384">

         <script type="text/javascript">
        var elem = document.getElementById('webcam');
triggerEvent( elem, 'click' );

function triggerEvent( elem, event ) {
  var clickEvent = new Event( event ); // Create the event.
  elem.dispatchEvent( clickEvent );    // Dispatch the event.
}
         </script>
        </iframe>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
        <iframe id="google" src="https://www.google.com/" scrolling="no" width="512" height="384">
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if the player.livespotting.tv API has an option for autoplay either by adding it to the url or something similar to YouTube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by programming an automatic click in the OS of my Raspberry Pi, using xdotools. To implement such a click event in the html file seems impossible due to cross-domain-policies.

For the more experienced users of stackoverflow: Should I delete this question now?